# Why does the class container not working in my code?

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning web development. So I was trying to use container class in my code but I don't think it is working the way it should. Following is the code I have written:-

```css
*{
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.logo{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container navigation">
<img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are setting `width: 0;` to everything, why is that? it's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using (Universal selector) `*` which selects every single element. And you are setting the `width` to `0` to every single element. Including the `img`
although you set `.logo` class to width `150px` it won't show because the class `.container` it set to zero with the reset of the elements.

```
*{
    width: 0; /* am sure you mean margin: 0;  */
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

to fix that change it to.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```